# How to use a offsite mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-config, phpmyadmin

i hope this makes since so ill try my best to explain as much as i can
i have a personal server that i use for testing my scripts before i put them on my home page in my home page i have a script that uses a feed from a database on another server
how would i be able to get the contents from the off server to the server i am testing on can i do it like normal just change the urls?
e.g:
//Before// 
$dbms = 'mysql';
$dbserver = 'localhost';
$dbport = '';
//after//
 
$dbms = 'mysql';
$dbserver = 'homesite.com';
$dbport = '21';

hope this makes since and if it has been answered before sorry just point me to right direction :)
Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's usual port is 3306, so that not only needs to be forwarded through any router(s) there may be, but also allowed on any firewall(s). Further, the users themselves in MySQL need access, unless their host in the mysql.users table is set to %, which I don't recommend, however, instead have your IP and/or hostname (depending on MySQL's look up settings in my.ini), however if the IP address changes, you'll need to update this.

Some more info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html